# Calling Function in a forloop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function inside the FOR LOOP. Since the format is same except for names of the data passed.

```
renderCharts(data1, axis1, 'mainchart1');
```

What i am doing

```
var data1 = [12, 45, 30, 80];
var axis1 = ['15 Jan', '22 Jan', '29 Jan', '5 Feb'];

var data2 = [89, 45, 30, 80];
var axis2 = ['15 Jan', '22 Jan', '29 Jan', '5 Feb'];

for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
    renderCharts("data"+i, "data"+i, "mainchart"+i)
}
```

Some reason its not working.

Comment: what error are you getting, sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're passing strings, not variables. If you want the function to work change the function call to:

```
renderCharts(window['data'+i],window['axis'+i],'mainchart'+i);
```

or replace window if the variables aren't declared in a global scope

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in the first example you are passing in 2 data objects and a string however in the loop you are passing in 3 strings and no data object, i believe in javascript you would need to use eval or something similar if you wanted to pass a data object called data(n) for each iteration of the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var data = [
             [12, 45, 30, 80],
             [89, 45, 30, 80]
           ];
var axis = [ 
             ['15 Jan', '22 Jan', '29 Jan', '5 Feb'],
             ['15 Jan', '22 Jan', '29 Jan', '5 Feb']
           ];

//for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++){ <== array index starts with 0
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    renderCharts( data[i], axis[i], "mainchart"+i)
}
```

You are not actually passing the two different variables-combos to the functions, but strings with their respective names. So your function doesn't actually get the data it needs, but just the variable names.

Either you transform your data to be held in arrays like above or use the approach of the other answers, to reference your variables via the `window[]` object.

For clarity the array approach should be preferred.

Comment: Why should the array approach be preferred? why not rely on the intrinsic qualities of JavaScript - like using square brackets to get property values from the window object?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Generally I prefer to have similar data grouped in one object. Mainly for the sake of clarity. On the other hand it is advisable to have as few as possible variables on the global scope to not get in conflict with other parts of the code or other libs. Last of all there is imo a very tiny performance advantage here, but that should be negligible here.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from now... but doesn't your approach sort of imply hard-coding all data in this case, or at least constructing these variables in the global scope? if -for instance- the arrays/objects in the data and axis variables are used and generated in different objects/functions/event handlers, they'd either all have to reconstruct the main data variable, or would have to refer to the global scope, in which case, the window['data'] (or window.data) syntax comes in handy once again

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem If they are generated by a function, just use `data.push( generatorFunction );` to add the data to the data object. I don't see an advantage on either side wrt to the data generation.

Comment: I'm not thinking of Data generation or quantity of vars in main scope. I'm with you there. I'm merely thinking of data access. in an ajax context eg, `form.submit` triggers a bunch of events on input fields, all data is processed and stored in a single object. In that scenario, I can't think of a better way than using `window.data`. It's a solid, easy to use/read/debug way to ensure all data is stored in the same object. That's all I meant. without the `window.` you might end up creating 10 different data objects, or worse:  making 10 ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

You are pass string to the function, not the variable you want.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put `eval` in your argument, because here you only give string argument.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
    renderCharts(eval("data"+i), eval("axis"+i), "mainchart"+i)
}
```

Comment: eval is EVIL... window['data'+i] evaluates string as variable name. Also `mainchart+i` has to be a string, eval that and enter a world of `undefined` errors. Although the reasoning is correct, this solution is a no-no

Comment: "eval is evil

The eval function (and its relatives, Function, setTimeout, and setInterval) provide access to the JavaScript compiler. This is sometimes necessary, but in most cases it indicates the presence of extremely bad coding. The eval function is the most misused feature of JavaScript." --Crockford. This is a classic case in point. Rule of thumb: don't use eval if there is an alternative (check my answer, there is an alternative). Google eval is evil for tons of articles, too

Comment: thanks, yes I've seen your answer and I voted up, it is better alternative

Comment: Merci bien... j'ai justement relu mes commentaires. Pardonnez-moi si j'avait l'air d'être un peu arrogant, quoi. C'est a cose de ça que je faits ce commentair ci en français. Je suis néerlandophone, alors, il me faut un peu de pratice, aussi. (@SO: Thanked him for the upvote and appologized if I came across arrogant in my comments. An apology always feels more heartfelt when it's in the other person's language. Plus, I can do with a bit of practice in French, too)